# How to format a date in Power Query? (Microsoft Excel 2016 - Query Editor - Advanced Editor?)

Tags: excel, editor, business-intelligence, powerquery

Using Microsoft Excel 2016 - Query Editor - Advanced Editor.

*I am not familiar with this language.*

```
let
   SettingsSheet = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
   #"TimeRange" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SettingsSheet,{{"From", type datetime}, {"To", type datetime}}),
   From = #"TimeRange"[From],
   #"To" = #"TimeRange"[To],
   DateFormatString = "mm/dd/yy",
   #"FormattedFrom" = Format(From,DateFormatString),
   ...
   (Further in the code I will need to build a URL string from it.)
```

When I search for the syntax to format date into a string, I always find this `Format(...,...)` function, but I get the error message

> The name 'Format' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: I look like the language is called Power Query.

Comment: The language in Power Query is called **M**.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language is call **Power Query**.
the expression I was looking for is `DateTime.ToText(DateTime, DateFormatString)` (instead of `Format(DateTime, DateFormatString)`).

Answer (score 4):

In Power Query UI when adding a custom column the syntax is...

= Date.ToText([Date],"MMM")

Answer (score 0):

It's called the Power Query M language. And for transforming a date into a desired format the Date.ToText function works great.

For example, the following code returns "31 dec 2023"

```
Date.ToText( 
  #date( 2023, 12, 31 ), 
  [Format="dd MMM yyyy"] 
)
```

Or you could return only the month text "december" by writing:

```
Date.ToText( 
  #date( 2023, 12, 31 ), 
  [Format="MMMM", Culture="nl-NL"] 
)
```

All possible combinations you can find here:

https://powerquery.how/date-totext/

Cheers, Rick